# Custom DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider Not Firing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation, data-annotations

I've created a custom `DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider`:

```
public class CustomValidatorProvider : DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider
{
    protected override IEnumerable<ModelValidator> GetValidators(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context, IEnumerable<Attribute> attributes)
    {
        //Do custom stuff...

        return base.GetValidators(metadata, context, attributes);
    }
}
```

And I've registered it in my `Global.asax`:

```
ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Add(new CustomValidatorProvider());
```

I put a breakpoint in the `GetValidators` method but it is never hit. My understanding is that this custom validator provider should be executed for each property in my model. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to override from `ModelValidatorProvider` and not `DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider`.  And the method signature should not have the attributes parameter and should be public:

```
public class CustomValidatorProvider : ModelValidatorProvider
{
    public override IEnumerable<ModelValidator> GetValidators(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        //Do custom stuff...

        //You cannot call the base here as ModelValidatorProvider is abstract.
        //return base.GetValidators(metadata, context);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I actually need access to the attributes because the `//Do custom stuff...` portion moves/edits some of the validation attributes on the model. I did try what you suggested, however, and the `GetValidators` method is still not firing.

Comment: Hmmm. It worked for me, and this is what was suggested in the Pro MVC 3 book by Adam Sanderson so not sure why it doesn't fire. So something else must be wrong and maybe not the provider you were inheriting from.  I hope you find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

ModelValidatorProviders.Providers already contain a DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.

Simply remove it before adding your custom DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.

```
ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Remove(ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.OfType<DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider>().First());

ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Add(new DependencyResolverModelValidatorProvider());
```